# Windows Boot Manager Breaks Ubuntu Boot Loader

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, windows, windows-8

When I ran Windows 8 the Ubuntu boot loader stopped launching Ubuntu and when I try to run Ubuntu again it says "Operating System not found". Is there a way to make it so that Ubuntu boots even after I run Windows 8? I installed it on a UEFI system. Windows 8 was pre-installed with the computer I installed Ubuntu on.

The problem started occurring when I ran Windows 8 from the Ubuntu boot manager, it showed the Microsoft Windows logo stretched to 640x400/640x480 resolution. When I ran it again it started up with an HP logo at the normal 1080p resolution. This is when the Windows Boot Manager option appeared in the list of boot loaders, and when the problem started occurring. When I ran "Ubuntu" from the list it said that the operating system was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run ubuntu from a live disc and install and run boot-repair, or alternatively you can use the boot-repair live disc..

Information on both can be found here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I installed a similar dual boot system recently with Win 10 pre-installed.These steps might help you solve the issue.

1. Boot into Win 8 and disable Fast Startup.
2. Boot into Ubuntu live USB.
3. Use efibootmgr to change boot order. You may google to get detailed understanding on it. Here's a summary.

   $ efibootmgr

This would list current order as below

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3000,0000,2001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

Then use below code to change the order bringing Ubuntu in front.

```
$sudo su
# efibootmgr -o 0000,1,3000,2001,2002,2004
```

4. Reboot and go to bios settings

There under boot settings, choose OS boot manager. Within OS boot manager bring Ubuntu up.

5. Reboot. It should work now. Usually, it is safe to re-enable Fast startup at this point.